# ETL: how to guess data types for messy CSVs with lots of nulls

Tags: ssis, etl

I often have to cleanse and import messy CSV and Excel files into my MS SQL Server 2014 (but the question would be the same if I were using Oracle or another database).

I have found a way to do this with Alteryx. Can you help me understand if I can do the same with Pentaho Kettle or SSIS? Alternatively, can you recommend another ETL software which addresses my points below?

1. I often have tables of, say, 100,000 records where the first 90,000 records may be null. Most ETL tools scan only the first few hundred records to guess data types and therefore fail to guess the types of these fields. Can I force Pentaho or SSIS to scan the WHOLE file before guessing types? I understand this may not be efficient for huge files of many GBs, but for the files I handle scanning the entire file is much better than wasting a lot of time trying to guess each field manually
2. As above, but with the length of a string. If the first 10,000 records are, say, a 3-character string but the subsequent ones are longer, SSIS and Pentaho  tend to guess nvarchar(3) and the import will fail. Can I force them to scan all rows before guessing the length of the strings? Or, alternatively, can I easily force all strings to be nvarchar(x) , where I set x myself?
3. Alteryx has a multi-field tool, which is particularly convenient when cleansing or converting multiple fields. E.g. I have 10 date columns whose datatype was not guessed automatically. I can use the multi-field formula to get Alteryx to convert all 10 fields to date and create new fields called $oldfield_reformatted. Do Pentajho and SSIS have anything similar?

Comment: Reading  Excel using IMEX can help. See the following article for more detail [http://blog.concentra.co.uk/2013/05/15/why-ssis-always-gets-excel-data-types-wrong-and-how-to-fix-it/

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a limit? I.e. if I modify the registry as suggested by the article, would Excel really scan all of the records in a, say, 100,000-record file? The connection manager for a CSV file in SSIS has a 'number of rows' input in the 'suggest types' box, but that is capped, too - at 1,000 or 10,000 records depending on the software version

Comment: in that case I've always been a big fan of sampling the file using Awk to get a more representative selection passed into staging: `awk 'BEGIN {srand()} !/^$/ { if (rand() <= .01) print $0}'` replacing the .01 with whatever percentage of the records you'd like to keep.

Comment: @Pythonista anonymous. I've not needed to alter the registry when I've adopted this solution before

Comment: But my problems arise precisely in situations where the vast majority of the records are null, and only a small percentage of the records are populated. This means that sampling is likely to result in samples where every single record is null...

Comment: I have always fallen back to the ELT approach. Use the import tool to import the file into a table whose datatypes are VARCHAR. Then use stored procedures to do that actual work of cleaning up, checking data types etc. In the end if you are importing data into a database, you must have defined a table somewhere with correct data types so the only challenge is getting the data in and checking it for data qualty

Answer (score 0):

A silly suggestion.  In Excel add a row at the top of the list that has a formula that creates a text string with the same length of the longest value in the column.

This formula entered as an array formula would do it..

```
=REPT("X",MAX(LEN(A:A)))
```

You could also use a more advanced VBA function to create other dummy values to force datatypes in SSIS.

I've not used SSIS or anything like it, but in the past I would have loaded a file into a table with columns ALL of varchar 1000 say so that all the data loaded, then processed it across into the main table using SQL that casts or removes the data values as I required.

This gives YOU Ultimate control not a package or driver.  I was very surprised to hear how this works!

Comment: I have done something very similar on small files, but I would like an ETL tool to automate it as much as possible, because this approach is tedious, or simply not feasible, when working with files Excel cannot handle, or with  too many tables (e.g. 10 tables each with 50 fields)